# organize terraform state in blob storage account

Tags: azure, terraform

I am new to using terraform for azure resource management.

I am using azure blob storage as a backend for terraform state file

My project consists of multiple repositories that map to a resource group in azure subscription

```
repository-a ---> azure-rg-a
repository-b ---> azure-rg-b
```

General structure of my repository consists of

```
repo-a
- src
- infra
   - env
      - dev.tfvars
      - xxx.tfvars (one per env)
   - main.tf
- tests
-------------------------------------------
repo-b
- src
- infra
   - env
      - dev.tfvars
      - xxx.tfvars (one per env)
   - main.tf
- tests
```

A single team is responsible for both the repositories and the resource groups. What is the *better* place to set up blob storage

### What I tried / have thought of doing

- Option A : keep a blob storage per resource group.

  - Cons : I don't like the idea of having those many storage accounts just for state management

```
azure-rg-repo-a
 - repo-a-storageaccount
   - tfstate (container)
     - tfstate.tfstate (state file)

azure-rg-repo-b
 - repo-b-storageaccount
   - tfstate (container)
     - tfstate.tfstate (state file)
```

- Option B : keep a blob storage in a separate resource group for infrastructure

```
azure-rg-infrastructure
 - repo-infra-storageaccount
   - tfstate (container)
     - repo-a.tfstate (state file for repo-a)
     - repo-b.tfstate (state file for repo-b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO I would use single storage for all state files, in AWS we enable versioning and prevent delete unless MFA root is used, tightly restrict access to that storage. Also when you have a shared Account that contains CICD for infra, it's a good pattern to use a single source of truth for state files.